# The obscure third type of error

Tags: powershell

We've all grown up hearing stories about the two types of errors that PowerShell has: terminating and non-terminating errors.

What describes a non-terminating error is that it just gets output to the error stream and allows the script to continue execution. However, it cannot be caught by a try/catch, as no exception is actually 'thrown'.

As for a terminating error, it both outputs the error to the error stream and, if unhandled, completely stop the script on its tracks, preventing anything below the line where the error occurred from being executed. It can be caught by try/catches.

Yet it appears that there is a third type of error, which I can't seem to find information about or a name for.

It is an error that is a sort of mixture between a terminating and a non-terminating error... When generated, it does not terminate the script, giving it the properties of a non-terminating error, but it can be caught by a try/catch, which gives it the properties of a terminating error!

And it's the most basic type of error there can be. It's exceptions thrown directly by .NET itself and not by PowerShell's functions or cmdlets.

Couple of examples:

- Division by 0.
- Calling an object's method with wrong arguments - be it wrong parameter types (that PowerShell can't auto-coerce), wrong number of arguments, etc... - example: `'a'.Split([object[]])`

Question is, what are these called and why do they differ from the other two types? The object is still an ErrorRecord, rather than an Exception, so they should really behave either like terminating or non-terminating errors, not a mutation of both.

Comment: Grown up with Powershell? Not unless you're only ten years old :-)

Comment: It's a metaphor for saying all blogs and documentation both from MS and otherwise you find out there only reference terminating and non-terminating errors.

Comment: But why can't I be 10? Maybe my nursery rhymes were hello worlds and bubble sorts. Have you tried singing a bubble sort? Hard work!

Comment: So, this is about definitive clarification about the *sorta*-terminating-errors? Or are you just wanting to vent your dislikes about Powershell? :)

Comment: @bzlm I'm not venting anything and I quite like powershell, just clarification. Don't understand why the downvote...

Comment: Good question. Yet another such error is missing command. I collect such cases at [PowerShellTraps](https://github.com/nightroman/PowerShellTraps) and included yours.

Comment: @RomanKuzmin You can include the .add method for hashtables when it throws an error for a key that already exists.

Comment: @Blaisem that's a documented .NET exception, see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.hashtable.add?view=net-6.0#exceptions

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft doesn't have a special name for "it", they simply call it a terminating error even though you need to set `$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"` to make them behave equally to a terminating error would (stop the script).

> Because Windows PowerShell does not recognize "nonsenseString" as a 
>   cmdlet or other item, it returns a **CommandNotFoundException** error.
>   **This terminating error** is trapped by the specific Trap statement.
>
> The following script example contains the same Trap statements with
>   a    different error:
>
> ```
>   trap {"Other terminating error trapped" }
>   trap [System.Management.Automation.CommandNotFoundException] 
>       {"Command error trapped"}
>   1/$null
> ```
>
> Running this script produces the following result:
>
> ```
>   Other terminating error trapped
>   Attempted to divide by zero.
>   At C:PS> errorX.ps1:3 char:7
>   +     1/ <<<< $null
> ```
>
> The **attempt to divide by zero** does not create a
>   CommandNotFoundException    error. Instead, that error is trapped by
>   the other Trap statement, which traps **any terminating error**.

Source: [about_Trap @ technet.microsoft.com](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847742.aspx)