# Does the hashtable's Add method for duplicate keys return a terminating or non-terminating exception when using catch?

Tags: powershell

When adding a duplicate key to a hashtable using the add method, a MethodInvocationException arises:

```
50|PS(5.1.19041) C:\Users [220908-11:58:48]> $h = @{}
51|PS(5.1.19041) C:\Users [220908-11:58:51]> $h.add('a',$null)
52|PS(5.1.19041) C:\Users [220908-11:58:53]> $h.add('a',$null)
Exception calling "Add" with "2" argument(s): "Item has already been added. Key in dictionary: 'a'  Key being added: 'a'"
At line:1 char:1
+ $h.add('a',$null)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentException
```

I prepared a couple of functions to test whether this is a non-terminating or terminating error. The results seem conflicting. Here is my first function and test run:

```
function test-ht {
    [cmdletbinding()]
    param(
        [hashtable]$ht,
        [string]$addKey,
        [string]$addValue,
        [string]$msg
    )

    $ht.Add( $addKey, $addValue )
    write-host "finished $msg"
}

$hash = @{}

test-ht -ht $hash -addKey 'test' -addValue '1' -msg 'trial 1'
test-ht -ht $hash -addKey 'test' -addValue '2' -msg 'trial 1 err'
test-ht -ht $hash -addKey 'test' -addValue '3' -msg 'trial 1 stop' -ErrorAction Stop
```

This outputs:

```
finished trial 1
Exception calling "Add" with "2" argument(s): "Item has already been added. Key in dictionary: 'test'  Key being added: 'test'"
At line:10 char:5
+     $ht.Add( $addKey, $addValue )
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentException

finished trial 1 err
test-ht : Exception calling "Add" with "2" argument(s): "Item has already been added. Key in dictionary: 'test'  Key being added: 'test'"
At line:18 char:1
+ test-ht -ht $hash -addKey 'test' -addValue '3' -msg 'trial 1 stop' -E ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [test-ht], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentException,test-ht
```

The 2nd command with `-msg 'trial 1 err'` seems to suggest it is a non-terminating error: the function prints the exception but still writes out its finished message. When I force it to `-ErrorAction Stop`, the finished message does not appear. This seems like normal behavior for a non-terminating error to me.

Then I run the second test, which is the same as above, except the `.Add` method is embedded in a try/catch statement:

```
function test-ht2 {
    [cmdletbinding()]
    param(
        [hashtable]$ht,
        [string]$addKey,
        [string]$addValue,
        [string]$msg
    )

    try {$ht.Add( $addKey, $addValue )} catch{}
    write-host "finished $msg"
}

$hash2 = @{}
test-ht2 -ht $hash2 -addKey 'test' -addValue '1' -msg 'trial 2'
test-ht2 -ht $hash2 -addKey 'test' -addValue '2' -msg 'trial 2 err'
```

This outputs:

```
finished trial 2
finished trial 2 err
```

Here, the catch suppresses the error. This suggests a terminating error to me, as catch does not suppress non-terminating errors, e.g.,

```
55|PS(5.1.19041) C:\Users [220908-12:05:36]> gci C:/missing; write-host 'finished'
gci : Cannot find path 'C:\missing' because it does not exist.
At line:1 char:1
+ gci C:/missing; write-host 'finished'
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\missing:String) [Get-ChildItem], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand

finished
56|PS(5.1.19041) C:\Users [220908-12:05:42]> try {gci C:/missing; write-host 'finished'} catch {}
gci : Cannot find path 'C:\missing' because it does not exist.
At line:1 char:6
+ try {gci C:/missing; write-host 'finished'} catch {}
+      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\missing:String) [Get-ChildItem], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand

finished
```

In summary, in the first run with `test-ht`, the `-msg 'trial 1 err'` printed the exception and continued, as if it were non-terminating. In the second run with `test-ht2` and the same function calls, the exception is suppressed by `catch`, as if it were a terminating error.

My questions:

1. Is this error non-terminating or terminating?
2. If it is non-terminating, why does the catch suppress the exception message?
3. If it is terminating, why does `test-ht` run to completion when adding a duplicate key?

Comment: It sounds like you're conflating _exceptions_ and _errors_ - the latter of which can be either terminating or non-terminating

Comment: So I should use error instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've recently learned about a 3rd type of error in PowerShell, possibly not documented or not well documented, where it produces an error that doesn't terminate the script but can be caught by try/catch, sort of an ambiguous non-terminating terminating error.

This is perhaps most easily reproduced with the example of dividing by 0.

```
1 / $null; 'done' #non-terminating behavior: 'done' is still printed.
```

vs

```
try { 1 / $null; 'done' }catch{'terminating error caught'} #terminating behavior: error is caught; 'done' is not printed.
```

The hashtable's `.add` method appears to fall into this same category. It may be related to exceptions thrown by .NET, as mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29883990/the-obscure-third-type-of-error).

Answer (score 1):

It is terminating:

```
    $x = @{}
try {
    $x.add('1',1)
    $x.add('1',2)
}
Catch {
    write-error "Terminating error"
}
Write-Error: Terminating error
```

test-ht runs into an exception if you add the 2nd time the same key:

```
$x =@{}
test-ht -ht $x -addKey a -addValue 2 -msg "haha"
finished haha
test-ht -ht $x -addKey a -addValue 2 -msg "haha"
Exception calling "Add" with "2" argument(s): "Item has already been added. Key in dictionary: 'a'  Key being added:....
finished haha
```

If you add the key before calling the function and after that call the function with the same key it gives you also the error:

```
$x =@{a=1}
test-ht -ht $x -addKey a -addValue 2 -msg "haha"
Exception calling "Add" with "2" argument(s): "Item has already been added. Key in dictionary: 'a'  Key being added:
```

test-ht2 is running to completion because there is nothing specified in the catch block which would stop the processing. Add return to the catch block to end processing of the script:

```
function test-ht2 {
    [cmdletbinding()]
    param(
        [hashtable]$ht,
        [string]$addKey,
        [string]$addValue,
        [string]$msg
    )

    try {$ht.Add( $addKey, $addValue )} catch{return}
    write-host "finished $msg"
}
```

With retrun in the catch it won't output "finished $msg" anymore.

Comment: Hi Toni, test-ht doesn't have a catch block. That's the point of my confusion why it would run to completion if it were a terminating error. I don't need a return in test-ht2, as the suppression of the error message is enough to demonstrate a terminating behavior. The summary is that without catch (as seen in test-ht) it acts like a non-terminating error, but with catch it acts like a terminating error. I would like to know why this is. An error should always be either non-terminating or terminating.

Comment: ups... did mess up with your functions... I update my answer